# How can I detect Node app startup folder on macOS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, macos

I am developing a cross-platform NodeJS server/app that is distributed as a prebuilt binary, built with `pkg`  (https://www.npmjs.com/package/pkg) for Windows, Mac and Linux.

At start-up, the app should generate a default `config.json` to the application directory. I'm detecting the current, start-up folder of the app with:

```
var startUpPath = process.cwd();
```

and this works on Windows, and Linux, but on macOS this fails and the file is generated to the user's home directory instead.

Further notes on **macOS**:

- this **works** when running the source code with `node myApp.js`
- this **works** when running the binary from command line with `./myApp`
- this **fails** when `myApp` is started by double-clicking in the Finder

The root cause seems to be that macOS processes always start in the *home directory*, not in *current directory*...?

I'm sure it's trivial but haven't figured it out.

Any pointers here?

Comment: `process.cwd()` is the directory from which you launched the Node app. The Finder is just assuming the user's home directory. Can you use `__dirname`? That's the directory for any given Node source file.

Comment: `__dirname` does not help, unfortunately. It gives the `/snapshot/` -folder of the `pkg` filesystem rather than the actual, physical path.

Answer (score 0):

Found a way eventually - in case somebody else is searching for a solution.

```js
// Detect startup folder at pkg runtime
if ( process.pkg ) {
    startUpPath = path.resolve(process.execPath + '/..');
} else {
    startUpPath = process.cwd();
}
```